# Trouble updating PHP version used by Apache on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, apache2, php, php-fpm, php-cli

I have multiple PHP versions (8.1/8.2/8.3) installed on my Ubuntu 22.04 system. I'm trying to switch between them using the `sudo update-alternatives --config PHP` command. However, I'm facing an issue where the CLI version changes successfully, but the PHP version on my Apache server remains unchanged when I visit my project URL in the browser.

I've attempted various solutions, including:

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php${version}
sudo a2dismod php8.1
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

I've also restarted FPM, but none of these solutions seem to work. I'd appreciate any insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. My operating system is Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP versions of the CLI, FPM and Apache PHP module are different tools for different purposes. There isn't a way to change the default for all at once.

#### Change default PHP FPM version

When using PHP FPM, `sudo a2enmod` will do nothing, because it's used by `mpm_prefork`. To change the default PHP FPM version used by Apache when running with `mpm_event` do this:

```
sudo a2disconf php8.1-fpm
sudo a2enconf php8.2-fpm
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Also, check your vhosts configs in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` for `SetHandler` directive.

#### Change default PHP CLI version

What you have tried with `update-alternatives` is the correct way to change the default PHP CLI version. For example:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.2
```

Make sure you have the corresponding `php-cli` package installed:

```
sudo apt install php8.2-cli
```

#### Editing the correct `php.ini`

Another thing you consider is that each of these used different `php.ini` files. For example, for PHP 8.2 you will have:

- `/etc/php/8.2/fpm` - The config file that is used by the FPM
- `/etc/php/8.2/cli` - The config file that is used by the CLI
- `/etc/php/8.2/apache2` - The config file that is used by the Apache  when using `mpm_prefork`

Comment: Can't we change both CLI and browser PHP version same time? When changing using provided command it change only for apache not for CLI

Comment: @Zahirabbas I updated my answer with some additional details.

Comment: Thank i made bash script to automate this thing [Click Here To See Blog Post](https://zaheerbadi.wordpress.com/2023/12/19/simplifying-php-version-switching-in-ubuntu-22-04-with-apache-and-fpm/)